# HTTP Remember me authentication

Tags: security, http, remember-me

I'm trying to write a simple HTTP remember me authentication system for users.

My users could be represented as such

```
{
"email" : "foo@bar.com",
"password" : "8EC41F4334C1B9615F930270A4F8BBC2F5A2FCD3" // sha1 hash of password
}
```

So my idea is that I need to create a cookie, with indefinite (really long) expiration time, that will hold some type of information to enable me to fetch the user from the database, therefore logging the user in.

My first idea was to just simply store the `email:password` string as a cookie. I thought this would be good since nobody else can really generate that type of information other than the user itself, and I could retrieve the user quite easily by simply comparing the `username` and `password` based on what's in the database.

However then I thought this wasn't really good. It turns the password digest into, effectively, a second password that's stored in the clear and passed over the wire in every request.

So then I thought maybe I could generate a `signature` each time the user logs in, which would basically be a random hash that is stored directly in the user object in the database.

The user logs in, it generates this signature that is stored, and the cookie holds this signature. Whenever you access the website, the site checks which user has that particular signature and logs the user in. Logging out will effectively erase the cookie, and new logins will generate a new random signature.

Does this approach take into account any other vulnerabilities?

I know, I should probably use a library already made for this, but this is just simply an exercise in web-security.

Comment: no user is ever trusted. not even trusted users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially what most sites do when you log in.  Yes, the cookie should hold a unique identifier for the user's "session".  The cookie should be essentially random.  Up to you whether to make it persistent across browser sessions.

Along with the cookie in your authentication DB, also store a timestamp of when the entry was created.  Cookies older than N seconds should be considered invalid (set N to your taste).  You can reset the timestamp each time the cookie is used so that idle sessions time out.

Note that the same user may want to have multiple sessions (do you ever log in to your Email account from both home and work?), so the concept here really is "session", not user.

Comment: But aren't sessions made to store information for that particular session (not long period of times)? Implementing or using a session system simply for remembering the user that is logged in seems quite an over-head.

Comment: A "session" can remember whatever you want it to remember, and for however long you specify...  The point is, what will you do if the same user logs in from multiple systems?

Comment: simply regenerate the `signature`. So they would have to re-login on the other computers. Not that of a issue. But I don't think sessions should be used for this sort of stuff... for short term things, like forms, or editing online documents, yes sessions are great, but for *remember me* type of authentication systems, they don't seem much versatile... so you would keep a session open for 2 years? That's really inefficient.

Comment: @Luca I think we have different notions of "session".  All I mean is the state associated with a login.  So the "session" is identified by signature and, in this case, has state equal to the Email address.  My suggestion amounts to using the signature (not the Email address) as the key, so that one user can be logged in from multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

Vulnerability point-of-view both are same! Cookie stealing and related mechanisms however browsers are smart enough now so you shouldn't worry about that.

Second approach is good in terms of privacy as well since it does not includes email address in the cookie. And it seems much more similar to like storing the sessionID which in your case you are generating a random hash and storing it in DB.

But i think it would be more wiser to use the first approach; you can add another layer to the digest and encrypt it with your some algo or private key; to be on safer side.

Comment: the issue with storing the hashed password in the cookie is that if someone is able to sniff your cookie, they will be able to re-login as yourself, even if you logout. The idea of a signature is that it's re-generated each time you login, so even if you lost your cookies, the attacker won't be able to do anything with them.